# Highlight TextBox on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have a TextBox "userName" with some text inside on page load.

I can highlight TextBox on the click event like this with jQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#userName').click(function() { selectAllText($(this)) });


        function selectAllText(textbox) {
            textbox.focus();
            textbox.select();
        }
```

}):

How can I highlight TextBox "userName" on page load? Much Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the script. It's so simple.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#userName').select();


});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     selectAllText($('#userName'));


    function selectAllText(textbox) {
        textbox.focus();
        textbox.select();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add $('#userName').focus() inside your doucument ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the DOM is ready before using js to access the object.